# Weird SQL Server slowdown when transferring files to AWS S3

Tags: sql-server, amazon-s3

I'm an experienced SQL Server DBA, but I just can't figure this out and wondering if anyone has experienced the same.

I have a 1 TB database running on an m4.10xlarge AWS instance. I have Full/Diff/Trans backups that happen on various schedules to a separate drive that's an "sc1" AWS Volume Type -- basically the cheap cold HDD storage type.

As an additional failsafe, I started experimenting with copying the files on this backup drive to S3. This is where my trouble and this great mystery began. I'm using the AWS CLI "sync" command to transfer files from the sc1 volume to S3, using a simple command like:

```
aws s3 sync "j:\sqlbackups" s3://****bucketname****/sqlbackups/
```

Because of the size of the backup files, an initial sync can take a few hours. Whenever I have this command running, at some point, SQL Server starts grinding down to being ridiculously slow. Queries timeout. Connections can't be established. CPU/Memory usage remains the same -- nothing out of the ordinary there. The only thing that's out of the ordinary is the Read Throughout on the Drive containing the Data file spikes:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/avqcyug700jdjzw/Screenshot%202019-12-08%2015.07.45.png?dl=0

BUT, there's no relation between this drive (the one with the SQL Server data file), and the sc1 backup drive. And the aws sync command shouldn't touch the drive with the data file.

It's not just SQL Server that slows down -- the whole Windows server that it's on slows down. Launching Chrome takes 30 seconds instead of 1. Reading an event in Event Viewer takes 60 seconds instead of <1 second.

Once this odd slowdown happens, I kill the aws sync command, but the problem still remains. I have to stop/restart the SQL Server service for the problem to go away.

I'm so confused as to how this could be happening. Any ideas?

EDIT 12/8/19 5:39PM EST

I've realized that it's not just the drive containing the data file whose throughput goes off the charts during an S3 transfer -- it's all the drives on the server. This led me to read about how EBS storage works, and I understand that EBS storage is network attached storage, and therefore uses network bandwidth.

This makes me think that the transfer of multi-TB files to S3 is saturating my network bandwidth, making my C/D/E drives perform really poorly. That would explain why every part of the Windows server, not just SQL Server, slows during during an S3 transfer.

What doesn't make sense is that as an m4.10xlarge instance, this server has a 10 Gbps connection, which means more than 1 Gigabyte / second bandwidth. My S3 transfers are only showing a usage of a max of 150 Megabytes/second. Plus, the m4.10xlarge instance type is EBS-Optimized, meaning there's dedicated bandwidth available for the EBS volumes that shouldn't conflict with the bandwidth being used for the S3 transfer.

Comment: Please don't post links to Dropbox; many users won't trust such links from a completely anonymous stranger. If something is important to your post, include it in the content of your question.

Comment: Have you opened Task Manager to see if antivirus tasks like Windows Defender are chugging down CPU scanning files before `aws s3 sync` has a chance to open the files for copying to S3? Also... Chrome on a server?

Comment: I don't actually use Chrome on the server. But I do have it installed, and was just firing it up as a measurement of how slow/fast the server is. Yes, I've made sure Windows Defender and Malwarebytes are NOT running. I can tell from the sync progress that files are being uploaded when the problem happens.

Comment: Dropbox links -- ok, understood. What's the best way of sharing a screenshot then?

Comment: Stack Overflow supports uploading images; but if it's a picture of text, you shouldn't be posting an image, but `text`.

Comment: Have you tried raising an AWS support ticket?

Comment: No not yet. I thought this was a SQL Server specific issue, so I thought the issue would be out of scope for AWS support, but I'm re-thinking that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using a server in the m4 class? Changing to an m5 should be as simple as stopping your EC2 instance, changing the instance type, and starting the instance back up? m5s have been out for two years and represent the latest architecture in that class (as of this writing).